# Images not loading, IE6 to IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having two problems:

1. My website is not forwarding from index.html on IE6 - IE9
2. Images are not loading on any page IE6 - IE9

For the first problem, if you go to http://www.matthallock.com/ the website cycles endlessly regardless if I link it to a file (e.g., /hamlet.html) or directly (e.g., http://www.matthallock.com/hamlet.html)

The second problem, more troublesome, is images appearing blank on Internet Explorer. Further, the problem appears to be with the jQuery, as the fixed sidebar also does not work.

I tried the  degrade for the lazy load, but that doesn't solve the problem. Curiously, if you go to my blog at blog.matthallock.com, there is no issue and the styling of the sidebar appears correct.

Appearance and functionality works properly in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest dropping support for IE6 (and probably IE7 too). I know that doesn't answer the problem, but it will solve a lot of other problems for you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;http://www.matthallock.com/hamlet.html">
```

You need to specify `url=` before actually giving the URL, otherwise it just reloads the current page.

```
$("img").lazyload({
    effect : "fadeIn",
    /*
      appear : function(elements_left, settings) {
        console.log("appear");
        console.log(elements_left);
        //console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
      },
      load : function(elements_left, settings) {
        console.log("load");
        console.log(elements_left);
        //console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
      }
    */
});
```

Your browser console gives you this one for free: "Expected identifier, string or number" - IE does not like trailing commas in object definitions, and because of your multiline comment your resulting code is:

```
$("img").lazyload({effect:"fadeIn",});
```

See that extra comma? Remove it, and everything magically works.

Comment: +1. yep. that's an IE-specific thing. (in fact IE is technically correct in enforcing it, according to the language specs; the other browsers are being lax in allowing the trailing comma)

Comment: Thank you so much guys, Stack to the rescue as usual.